# SQL Server constraints about Relations between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on a SQL Server project that allows the users of a shopping website to insert their reviews for the product they bought.

Basically, I have 4 tables:

- `Customer`: (Customer_ID, Username, Telephone_number, Grade)
- `Product`: (Product_ID, Product_code, Name)
- `Review`: (Review ID, Title, Content, Product_ID, Customer_ID)
- `Bill`: (Bill_ID, Date, Product_ID, Customer_ID)

I've got two problems:

- Firstly, I don't know how to force that only people who bought a product can review it.
- Secondly, I don't know how to increase the grade in Customer table by a certain number of points (bonus points) after they review of a product.

Can anyone tell me how to solve these problems, especially in SQL Server code?

Comment: And how do you know if a customer purchased a product?  It is not clear in your data model.  Incidentally, I would recommend deleting this question and splitting it into to.  You are asking two questions.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways that you can do to protect your `Review` table from inserting such these records and it is best to handle these in your server-side or client-side code but as a design point of your DB, I think the best is to:

Design your `Review` table like:

```
(Review_ID, Title, Content, Bill_ID)
```

and set you `Bill_Id` column to not allow NULL, so that every review record must relate to a bill (shopping) record then you can handle error in your code which warns the users or...

Also if your grade is only about reviewing, you can set bonus (grade) a ratio of reviews so the grade would be like:

```
SELECT 5*COUNT(*)  -- for example two reviews = 10 bonus
FROM Review
GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

And one more time I suggest you to handle all these in your code not in your DB.

Another suggestion is (If the logic and business of your application is based on database - which a shopping website is not!!) - is to create a stored procedure for `INSERT` operation like `usp_ReviewInsert` and call it in your code as a user wants to post a review,  then your stored procedure handles all validating stuff (like relation between Bill and Review) and all updating stuff (like updating grade to a higher) and the insert operation in itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very useful to me

Comment: so good. you may mark this as answer so your question will be answered.